# When pressed Letter, Write the letter a Edittext

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a problem
As it can be seen in the picture there are 3 Buttons and a EditText

[image]

Need to write in the box which button is pressed and write the corresponding character in the EditText. Just like a keyboard.
Sorry for my bad English.
Like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a `StringBuilder`, then every time you press a button add that characted to the StringBuilder and update the content of EditText.

Just a quick snippet:

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(EDITTEXT_ID_PATH);

    Button button_q = (Button) findViewById(BUTTON_Q_ID_PATH);
    button_q.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s.append("q");
                et.setText(s);
            }
        });

    Button button_e = (Button) findViewById(BUTTON_E_ID_PATH);
    button_e.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s.append("e");
                et.setText(s);
            }
        });

    Button button_w = (Button) findViewById(BUTTON_W_ID_PATH);
    button_q.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s.append("w");
                et.setText(s);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use switch case, here is the completed code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    EditText et1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                et1.append("Q");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                et1.append("E");
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                et1.append("W");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: YES THIS! Thanks, great master :)